# Better to Throw NotSupportedException Inside or Outside of Task?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

We have a downstream system, an ERP system, that can expose its tables via SOAP. The web service that it publishes typically has Create, Update and Delete methods. We then generate the proxy on our end with svcutil including async methods. Finally, we put an ACL in front of this for other systems to interact with.

We also just discovered an important invariant - costing information for items cannot be updated by ANYTHING other than the ERP system itself. However the really dumb API will allow consumers to do this.

My idea to get around this is to subclass the WCF proxy and have explicit implementations for updating that throw `NotSupportedException`. No, this won't stop a developer from generating his own proxy and doing it. But at least we can guarantee that it cannot happen when going through our ACL.

```
    Update_Result Item_Port.Update(Update request)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
```

For async methods, I could either do

```
    Task<Update_Result> Item_Port.UpdateAsync(Update request)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
```

OR

```
    Task<Update_Result> Item_Port.UpdateAsync(Update request)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew<Update_Result>(() =>
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        });
    }
```

From an async perspective, which one is more 'correct?'

Comment: BTW, instead of using `StartNew()` with a throwing lambda, you can instead use `TaskCompletionSource` and `SetException()`.

Comment: f this question is about .NET 4.0 without any Async extensions, it would have been better to remove/avoid the usage of C#-5.0 term `async` in formulating the question because it confuses

Comment: I keep forgetting that .net 4.5 is c# 5.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two will have different behavior.

In the first case, the caller of this API will get the `NotSupportedException` immediately upon calling this method.

In your second case, the caller will receive a faulted `Task<T>` (or one that will become faulted soon after the call is made).  This will cause the exception in the task's continuation or when the task's value is fetched (via `task.Result`).

Given your goals, I would personally go with the first method.  This has less overhead (you're not creating a task), and it makes the call site immediately obvious that something is wrong.  While it's not as good as a compile time error, this will be far less likely to be missed during debugging, as it would throw even if the task was called in a "fire and forget" manner.

Comment: To support this opinion, I'd tell that any delayed, invoked, collateral and/or indirect "good intentions" (or time booby traps) are very irritating and confusing. Note aslo  that in second case,  a huge amount of actions can happen before task's continuation or fetching its result. There are possibilities that it will not even be continued or its result fetched!!!